# How to increase code coverage for an asynchronous operations in Nodejs using Sonar, Jest and Supertest

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, jestjs, supertest

How can we increase code coverage for asynchronous operations in Nodejs using Sonar, Jest and Supertest. For the following code i wrote a test case and check the status as 200.

```
api.post('/activate', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { action, requestId } = req.body
  DeviceManager.ActivateDevices(req.body) //call device activation
  res.send({ requestId, message: 'Request is on processing', action, status: Config.STATUS.PENDING })
  next()
})
```

```
  test('should activate a device', async done => {
    const res = await request(app)
      .post('/api/v1/devices/activate')
      .send({
        mac:'YUINH6767'
        requestId: '791',
      })
    expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200)
    done()
  })
```

Here the statement `DeviceManager.ActivateDevices(req.body)` is an async activity.
This action will be complete at some point say for example after 1 min. In this case how to write a proper test case in order get a good code coverage.

Comment: SonarQube only displays the data you have provided. It cannot increase the code coverage.

Comment: @JeroenHeier. Thanks for the response.  yes.. correct. My question is like how can i improve the coverage of asynchronous code using Jest/superTest

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are not waiting for async operation to get completed. You should await the async call before sending response to the user. something like

```
api.post('/activate', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { action, requestId } = req.body
  await DeviceManager.ActivateDevices(req.body) //call device activation
  res.send({ requestId, message: 'Request is on processing', action, status: Config.STATUS.PENDING })
  next()
})
```

Comment: Hi Ashish,
As per my requirement that activity should be happened in background. So I could n't use  await. Is there any other way I could test background task along with supertest